# How to fixed infinity height of stepper?

Tags: flutter, stepper

I have a problem about my Stepper Horizontal because even I only have one TextFormfield, it is still scrollable because it says the height is infinity.

```
Container(
            child: new Stepper(
              steps: _mySteps(),
              controlsBuilder: _createEventControlBuilder,
              type: StepperType.horizontal,
              currentStep: this._currentStep,
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
               onStepTappe: (){
               }
               onStepContinue: (){
               }
               onStepCancel: (){
               }
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
```

> ════════ (69) Exception caught by rendering library
>   ════════════════════════════════════════════════ RenderRepaintBoundary
>   object was given an infinite size during layout. User-created ancestor
>   of the error-causing widget was:    Stepper
>   NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

```
You can put height in your container like this 

Container(height: value)
```